# What does the feedback link do?

Tags: support

I recently happened to be on the site while I wasn't logged in, and I noticed that on each post, where the comment link normally is, is a feedback link. When you run your mouse over it, it changes to the question, "Was this post useful to you?" followed by yes/no buttons.

If someone clicks one of those buttons, what happens? Does it count as an up- or downvote? Does it flag the post? I can't see anything in the UI which would seem to be the result of one of those buttons being clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the anonymous feedback feature for people who don't have the ability to vote, there's a whole tag about it on the parent meta (Can't seem to find a blog post about it):

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-feedback?sort=active&pagesize=50

As far as I can tell we're collecting the data in the system but don't really use it for anything yet.

The questions show up for users with 10k reputation in the review section, but right now it just shows you which questions are getting the most anonymous feedback so we can improve/vote on questions which are being voted on by people on the internet who might not have an account or can't vote.

Perhaps as this corpus of information gets larger we can do something with this information but I really only go in there every once in a while to see if there's a page getting a bunch of "this is not useful" links.